# Getting a list of installed VPN Profiles Programatically - iOS

Tags: ios, vpn, appsettings

Is it possible for an app to programatically get a list of VPN profiles that are installed on an iOS Device?

I am guessing that this shouldn't be possible since this information lies outside of the app's sandbox. However, I have seen the `NetworkExtension` framework with the `NEVPNConnection` and `NEVPNManager` classes that allow you to run a VPN on the fly. If you can setup a VPN on the fly, it might also be possible to get the existing VPN profiles.

Also, `NEVPNManager` has the following method that seems to load some preferences:
`(void)loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionHandler NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0);`

So, it would be great if you could let me know if it is possible to fetch a list of installed VPN profiles.